# Using (templated) function-scope static address as Unique ID

Tags: c++, template, pointers, polymorphism, static

```
typedef const bool* const TypeID;
template<typename>
TypeID TypeIdOf() noexcept {
        static const bool idLoc(0);
        return &idLoc;
}
```

I'm using this function to return from some derived classes to differentiate them at runtime, by returning from this function, templated as the class. ie:

```
class Object
{
...
        TypeID Type() const = 0;
        template<typename T> bool IsType() const
        { return Type() == TypeIdOf<T>(); }
...
};
class DerivedObject:
public Object
{
...
        TypeID Type() const override { return TypeIdOf<DerivedObject>(); }
...
};
```

It's worked so far, but it took me a while to decide to use it, and I'm still having some worries about using it in the long-term. So I'm asking my first question here: is this code OK? Is it thread safe? Could this throw any exceptions? Thanks.

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @AryanParekh Should I edit my question and add the concrete code I'm working on? I wouldn't be able to do that right now, because of circumstance, but I could do that later. Or should I remove the question, and ask again with said code when I have time? Sorry.

Comment: That's alright, but do not post a new question, you can simply [edit] the existing one.

Comment: @AryanParekh Understood. I'll find some time later. Cheers.